# how to encrypt xml file with prefix

Tags: c#, xml, encryption

I did xml encryption data using RSA and AES. For the encryption value is successful displayed but the only issue is element node of encrypted data don't have any prefix.

Please advise if there's any method to do it. Thanks in advance

I referring to this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.encryptedxml(v=vs.110).aspx for creating the encryption

output I get:

```
   <EncryptedData xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" />
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
        <CipherData></CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
      </EncryptedKey>
    </KeyInfo>
    <CipherData>
      <CipherValue></CipherValue>
    </CipherData>
  </EncryptedData>
```

desired output:

```
      <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" />
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
            <xenc:CipherData></xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
          </xenc:EncryptedKey>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>
          <xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
      </xenc:EncryptedData>
```

Comment: Your desired output would be invalid XML as the prefix xenc is not declared.

Comment: how to create it? any idea @chrisis

Comment: I don't know c# so I can't answer that. I was just pointing out that you either declare the namespace on an element or, declare a prefix with that namespace. The actual output has all elements in the http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc# which appears correct to me. The point being that whether you use a prefix assigned to the namespace or the namespace itself, as parsed XML they are identical.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I have the same issue. Need to add those prefixes.